# What is the id under %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\15.0 and where does it come from?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-registry, dictionary, id

Under `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\15.0` I find a directory whose name consists of 8 alphanumericals. Below that directory, I have a directory `Proofing` which contains   the file `RoamingCustom.dic`. This file apparently stores the words I added to the dictionary via my Office applications.

I am not sure where this id originates from and what service or application is responsible for creating it. I also don't know why this needs to be a changing id and why the `RoamingCustom.dic` cannot be just stored in a directory whose name is equal accross multiple machine (at least when using `%APPDATA%`).

I'd like to have a means that returns this id in a reliable way (Powershell or cmd.exe).

The background of the question is that I'd like to automate the management of `RoamingCustom.dic` accross various installations and domains.

Comment: Have you tried searching the registry and filesystem for that ID? If you did it in other contexts you may be able to deduce what it's for.

Comment: In fact, I did and only found it under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Proofing Tools\1.0\Custom Dictionaries`.